# Can't fetch data from mysql_fetch_array() in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my PHP:   (that code does it's job well)

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {
$username = $_COOKIE["user"]; 
$pass = $_COOKIE["password"];
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$username'")or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
        {
        //if the cookie is present but has the wrong password, they are  taken to the login page 
        if ($pass != $info['password']) 
        {
            header("Location: login.php"); 
            exit();
        }  
        else //if the cookie is present and doesn'T have the wrong password they are shown the admin area    
        { 
            include 'header.php';
        }
    }

}
else //if the cookie is present and doesn'T have the wrong password they are shown the admin area    
        {
            header("Location: login.php"); 
            exit();
        }
```

but later on the same page, I try to access data from the $info variable and nothing comes out.  I know i'm doing something wrong, but can't figure out what...

```
<?php print $info['name']?>
```

If I make my variable global, how do I use it the while ?

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $check );
    while ($info.....???)
        {
                        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any warnings/errors in your output or in your log files?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 2):

#### When you do:

```
while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
{
   //
   // do things with info:
   //...
   //
}
```

The last $info is false (no more record), when it reaches beyond the last record. So $info is false, the while loop terminates, there is no more database "info" in it.

#### As a workaround, we save the first $info in **$info0**,

```
$info0 = false;

while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
{
  if(! $info0)
  {
    $info0 = $info;
  }
   //
   // do things with info:
   //...
   //
}
```

you use **$info0** instead of $info after the while loop.

```
<?php echo $info0['name']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $info variable is localized to the if statement.

Make the $info variable global.

Comment: If I make my variable global, how do I use it the while ? 

    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$username'")or die(mysql_error());
 $info = mysql_fetch_array( $check );
  while ($info)
   {
                            }

Comment: You could actually just set up a new variable and set `$info['name']` equal to it inside your while statement.

Comment: `$name=''` then in the while statement: `$name=$info['name']`

Answer (score 0):

After the `while` loop, use the [mysql_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-data-seek.php) function:

```
$info = mysql_data_seek($check, 0) ? mysql_fetch_array($check) : null;
```

Of course, [you MUST avoid to use all PHP functions that begin with **mysql_**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

if you want use `$info` in `if(isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {` is okay but if you want to use `$info` outside `if(isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {` there will be a problem becaause `$info` not initialization before `if(isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {` so your code will be like this

```
$username = $_COOKIE["user"]; 
$pass = $_COOKIE["password"];

if(isset($_COOKIE["user"])) {
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$username'")or die(mysql_error()); 
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array( $check ))
        {
        //if the cookie is present but has the wrong password, they are  taken to the login page 
        if ($pass != $info['password']) 
        {
            header("Location: login.php"); 
            exit();
        }  
        else //if the cookie is present and doesn'T have the wrong password they are shown the admin area    
        { 
            include 'header.php';
        }
    }

}
else //if the cookie is present and doesn'T have the wrong password they are shown the admin area    
        {
            header("Location: login.php"); 
            exit();
        }   


$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$username'")or die(mysql_error()); 
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $check );
```